# Remove base key object from array of object using lodash or javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the array of objects as below which has a base object with a set of values.

I need to remove the base object of all the data and make it as the Expected result below.

Example array

```
[
     {
        "100": {
            "id": "100",
            "name": "Test name 1"
        },
        "101": {
            "id": "101",
            "name": "Test name 2"
        },
        "102": {
            "id": "102",
            "name": "Test name 3"
        }

     }
]
```

**Expected Result**

```
[        
        {
            "id": "100",
            "name": "Test name 1"
        },
        {
            "id": "101",
            "name": "Test name 2"
        },
        {
            "id": "102",
            "name": "Test name 3"
        }         
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), get the values of the object with [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), and flatten the results to a single array by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const data = [{"100":{"id":"100","name":"Test name 1"},"101":{"id":"101","name":"Test name 2"},"102":{"id":"102","name":"Test name 3"}}];

const result = [].concat(...
  data.map(o => Object.values(o))
);

console.log(result);
```

With lodash you can use [`_.flatMap()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#flatMap) with [`_.values()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#values):

```js
const data = [{"100":{"id":"100","name":"Test name 1"},"101":{"id":"101","name":"Test name 2"},"102":{"id":"102","name":"Test name 3"}}];

const result = _.flatMap(data, _.values);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```